# TinyMCE in Angular project

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am trying to use `TinyMCE` in my angular application, but I always got this error:

> "...node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member
> 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

Could you please tell me what I need to do to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the `@tinymce/tinymce-angular` library?

If you did, all you have to do is `import { EditorModule } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';` into your app-module or any other module of your choosing.

You can read up on how to get the API key for your app and other initialization configuration for TinyMCE on their official website.